# How to match Java regex in switch case?

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a Java code so that for any word that begins with "Foo", do something and for all that begin with "Bar" do something else.

```
for(String str: stringList) {
    switch (str) {
        case Foo*: // do something. then break.

        case Bar*: // do something else. break.
    }
}
```

Now, how do I do this regex matching in java?

Comment: does startsWith help if you dont want to use switch

Comment: switch'es in Java are constructs designed to operate on `int` values, and pretty much nothing more. Until [Project Amber](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/) completes (and that won't be for quite a long time), things that allow `switch` to work over types different than `int` pretty much border a hack (you can look in compiled bytecode of switch statements for yourself). With that said, no, there isn't anything which will support both `switch` and some kind of pattern in Java for the near future.

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/8088370

Answer (score 5):

Switch statements require string literals and do not currently accept regex patterns.  But you can easily enough achieve the logic you want just using `if` and `else`:

```
for (String str: stringList) {
    if (str.matches("Foo.*")) {
        // do something
    }
    else if (str.matches("Bar.*")) {
        // do something else. break.
    }
}
```

We could have used `String#startsWith` or substring, but I used `matches` to illustrate that a regex pattern can be used.

### Demo

Comment: Usually it's better to compile patterns outside of loops.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You're right, I missed that.  We could use formal pattern matchers instead and define them outside the loop.  Feels a bit heavy duty for this question however.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a switch statement. Use a if-else-if instead:

```
for(String str: stringList) {

    if(str.startsWith("Foo")){
        // do something
    } else if(str.startsWith("Bar")){
        // do something
    }
}
```